# How to limit the number of concurrent jobs in powershell?

Tags: optimization, powershell, limits

I'm trying to get uptime of 2000+ computers.
As winrm isn't configure on these computers I cannot use invoke-command -computername $computers.
So I tried to use `start-job` to speed up things but start-job doesnt come with a `throttleLimit` parameter as invoke-command. So my script fires large amount of powershell.exe until it kills my memory... Is there a way to limit the concurrent jobs?

this is what I've got now:

```
$jobs=@()
Get-QADComputer -SearchRoot $OU -SizeLimit 3000 |%{
    $jobs+= Start-Job -ArgumentList $_.name -ScriptBlock {(param $cn)
    if (Test-Connection -Quiet $cn){
        $lastboottime=(Gwmi -computername $cn -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).lastbootuptime
        $sysuptime = (Get-Date) – [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($lastboottime)

        $cn +" "+$sysuptime.days
    }
}
}

$jobs|%{ Wait-Job $_ -Timeout 30 |Receive-Job ;Remove-Job $_}
```

Comment: Have you read here? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/04/04/scaling-and-queuing-powershell-background-jobs.aspx or here: http://www.poshpete.com/powershell/creating-a-throttle-for-background-tasks-without-rewriting-your-code-v2

Comment: @C.B. Thanks, now I did. I found this solution a bit complicated, i will check this one before which i found more readable : http://www.poshpete.com/powershell/creating-a-throttle-for-background-tasks-without-rewriting-your-code-v2

Comment: :) was my second link...

Comment: If that second link is the one I think it is (it's currently being blocked by my proxy, and Google thinks the site has been compromised), I have successfully used `Limit-Jobs` myself and like it.

Comment: @alroc yes this is about limit-jobs function. Seems nice as it doesnt need code modification, just a call of the limit-jobs function before start-job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is a viable way to do it, you don't have to use jobs at all. `Get-WMIObject` takes a `String[]` for the `ComputerName` parameter, and if multiple computernames are passed, it will poll multiple machines simultaneously (I think up to 32, but I don't recall exactly) & return an extra field in the results, `PSComputerName`

You can do this much more simply.

```
$servernames = @();
$servernames += get-qadcomputer -searchroot $ou|select name|%{if(test-connection -quiet $_.name) {$_.name}}
get-wmiobject -computername $servernames win32_operatingsystem|select PSComputername,LastBootTime
```

then calculate your uptime from there for each computer.

Edit (Kayasax) : here is the final recipe :

```
$alive=@()
$obj=@()

Get-QADComputer -SearchRoot $ou -SizeLimit 4000 |select -ExpandProperty name |foreach-object {
    if (Test-Connection -Quiet -count 1 $_){ $alive+=$_ }
}

Get-wmiobject -computername $alive -Class Win32_OperatingSystem |select PSComputerName, lastBootUpTime |foreach-object{
    $sysuptime = (Get-Date) – [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($_.lastBootUpTime)
    $props=@{"name"=$_.PSComputername;"uptime"=$sysuptime.days}
    $obj+= new-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -property $props
}

$obj |sort-object uptime -desc
```

Comment: Thanks seems promising ! i've no time to test it today, will try tomorrow.

Comment: My general rule of thumb is this: If a cmdlet can take an array of computernames (or whatever) as a parameter to operate on a batch of "things", it has probably implemented any parallelism better than I can via jobs. Plus, creating lots of jobs can result in a lot of overhead.